# Null Pointer Exception For Map when getting size

Tags: java, collections

It gives Null Pointer Exception when we get size after putting null Map into Map. 
When we know that HashMap is allowed to put null value and key. 
Why this happen when we put null Map.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Map<String, Integer> n=new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        n.put("1", 1);
        System.out.println(n.size());
        Map<String, Integer> nn=null;
        n.putAll(nn);
        System.out.println(n.size());
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not getting the NPE calling `n.size()`; you're getting the NPE on the previous line when calling `n.putAll(nn)`. Although individual keys and values in a HashMap are allowed to be null, the map argument to `putAll` is not. [The documentation of `HashMap.putAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#putAll-java.util.Map-) says:

> throws `NullPointerException` - if the specified map is null

You can use a non-null empty map if you want to `putAll` 0 entries.

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` allows `null` value, but the entire object should not be `null`.

`putAll` calls the operations on the collection that you are trying to add and its null.

Answer (score 0):

You assign `null` to nn here:

```
Map<String, Integer> nn=null;
```

And put it another map here:

```
  n.putAll(nn);
```

Hence `NPE`

Answer (score 0):

```
n.putAll(nn);
```

is throwing a `NPE`. If we look in the source, the first line of `HashMap.putAll(Map<K, V> map)` is `int numKeysToBeAdded = m.size();`

Since `m` in above line is null, a `NPE` is thrown.